# How can I know which terminal my flight departures from and to which one it arrives?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airlines

I am traveling with [LAN Airlines](http://www.lan.com/es_es/sitio_personas/ofertas/vuelos-baratos-frankfurt/madrid-frankfurt/) this weekend. I'll take a flight from Madrid to Frankfurt but I don't know from which terminal my flight departs or which terminal my flight arrives to. My ticket only states that the flight takes off from Madrid and lands in Frankfurt.

I guess that this information will appear in the boarding pass but I was wondering if there is any way of knowing it in advance (besides sending an email to the company which I have just done).

I've been looking and I've found that the main offices of LAN Airlines in Madrid are in the T4 terminal but I don't know if their flights take off from here or from the older terminals.

Does anyone know which terminal do LAN flights take off from in Madrid and to which one they arrive in Frankfurt?

Comment: Think of terminals as mini-airports within the airport. If an airline uses a terminal, then that terminal is for departures and arrivals..

Comment: Note that there is a *huge* difference between T4 and T4S in Madrid -- calculate approximately 20 minutes of extra time to reach T4S.

Comment: `Does anyone know` : No.  It is all subject to change.  Most likely, the gate assignment may be likely to change.  The terminal probably won't.  However, airlines are known to use services of other airlines.  Feel free to follow the information in jcaron's answer, which looks very promising.  But KNOW that information should not be thought of as being in stone.  Count on the idea that details are subject to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look up a comparable flight for today on [FlightAware.com](https://flightaware.com/). This is best done as close to your date of departure as possible, as terminal use may change occasionally. You can usually see tomorrows flights as well.

For example:

[image]

https://flightaware.com/live/flight/LAN704/history/20160218/1415Z/LEMD/EDDF

The websites of the respective airports will also usually have this information, especially the outbound airport. Terminal info on arrivals varies between airport websites.

Comment: "as terminal use may change occasionally"? are you sure? did you mean "gate"?

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Yes, it happens occasionally, sometime with short notice. [Example 1](http://loyaltylobby.com/2015/10/12/british-airways-terminal-changes-for-eight-long-haul-destinations-from-t5-to-t3-at-london-heathrow/), [Example 2](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/flightops/public/en_us?p_faqid=4649), [Example 3](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/corporate/announcements/announcement/terminal-change-for-gatwick-flights).

Comment: @neo  I guess only if the airline operates in these terminals, I assume it's hard to move the check-in desks in short notice..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Maybe those changes were planned for a longer time but only announced to the public a few days before. I just saw [this change linked](https://lfn.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5410/related/1) which actually reads like it was done and planned on short notice. Check-in desks are not always exclusively operated by the airline itself, especially in airports where they have few flights.

Comment: @neo true, alliance members share desks.. that's one of the benefits for airlines when joining alliances.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I've also gotten quite a few boarding passes printed on generic "Acme Aviation Service" paper I don't think it's always possible to have enough staff and technology ready at a small airport with only a few flights. [Here is one such company](http://www.ahs-de.com/en/locations).

Answer (score 3):

The information is actually available on the LAN website:

1. Go to the [LAN website](http://www.lan.com/en_ue/sitio_personas/index.html)
2. Select "Flight Status"
3. Select the date (only available for days around today, but since you're flying this week-end, the info is there)
4. Enter flight number or departure/arrival airports
5. Click on "See more information"

The result: Saturday's flight leaves from T4 and arrives in T1.

Answer (score 1):

If your boarding pass doesn't say the information, you should check the airport maps, the map indicates wich airlines are in each terminal, for example, terminal 1  for Canada air, Lufthansa and American airlines (arrivals or departures) each airport is different but they all have free accesss to their maps and airline location on their websites. Other option is to download a flight tracker app  her is one: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/flightview-free-real-time/id399057337?mt=8 
but sometimes those apps are not 100% right.